# Java stream's iterator forces flatmap to traverse substream before getting the first item

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream

I have the need to create an iterator out of a stream of streams. Both the parent and the child streams are composed by non-interfering stateless operations and the obvious strategy is to use flatMap.

Turns out that iterator, at the first "hasNext" invocation, traverse the entire first substream and I don't understand why. Despite `iterator()` is a terminal operation is clearly stated that it shouldn't consume the stream.
I need that the objects generated from the substream are generated one by one.

To replicate the behaviour I've mocked my real code with a sample which shows the same:

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FreeRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();
        Iterator<C> iterator = Stream.generate(() -> null)
                .takeWhile(y -> x.incrementAndGet() < 5)
                .filter(y -> x.get() % 2 == 0)
                .map(n -> new A("A" + x.get()))
                .flatMap(A::getBStream)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(B::toC)
                .iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("after hasNext()");
            C next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(next);
        }

    }

    private static class A {
        private final String name;

        public A(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println(" > created " + name);
        }

        public Stream<B> getBStream() {
            AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
            return Stream.generate(() -> null)
                    .takeWhile(x -> c.incrementAndGet() < 5)
                    .map(n -> c.get() % 2 == 0 ? null : new B(this.name + "->B" + c.get()));
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static class B {

        private final String name;

        public B(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println(" >> created " + name);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public C toC() {
            return new C(this.name + "+C");
        }

    }

    private static class C {

        private final String name;

        public C(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println(" >>> created " + name);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

When it is executed it shows:

```
 > created A2
 >> created A2->B1
 >>> created A2->B1+C
 >> created A2->B3
 >>> created A2->B3+C
after hasNext()
A2->B1+C
after hasNext()
A2->B3+C
 > created A4
 >> created A4->B1
 >>> created A4->B1+C
 >> created A4->B3
 >>> created A4->B3+C
after hasNext()
A4->B1+C
after hasNext()
A4->B3+C

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In debug it's clear that `iterator.hasNext()` triggers the generation of objects B and C.

The desired behaviour, instead, is:

```
 > created A2
 >> created A2->B1
 >>> created A2->B1+C
after hasNext()
A2->B1+C
 >> created A2->B3
 >>> created A2->B3+C
after hasNext()
A2->B3+C
 > created A4
 >> created A4->B1
 >>> created A4->B1+C
after hasNext()
A4->B1+C
 >> created A4->B3
 >>> created A4->B3+C
after hasNext()
A4->B3+C
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm currently convinced that I'm missing something in the `A.getBStream()` method and I'm generating the stream the wrong way, but I can't figure it why

Comment: Not related to your question, but it seems odd that you generating the Integer values in a predicate and not in a supplier. Why not: Stream.generate(() -> x.incrementAndGet()).takeWhile(n -> n < 5).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).map(n -> new A("A" + n))...

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible to get the behaviour you are wanting.  The A#getBStream method puts two instances of B in to the returned stream, and flatMap is going to operator on both of them.  It's not clear from your question or example why it matters when the B and C instances are created.

Comment: @RonMcLeod Yes, reviewing the mock it doesn't make clear sense, but it is derived from generating a stream from an iterator. In the specific case the iterator traverse the sheets of an excel file filtering them using the sheet's name. I couldn't generate the sheet directly in the supplier because the `takeWhile` would have come after the invocation of `next()` method from the original iterator

Comment: @RonMcLeod the A#getBStream generates a stream, so I thought that its behaviour would be to generate one instance of B at time. This actually happens if I use, rather than `Stream.iterator()` method, the `Stream.forEach()` method, which indeed showed the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way out, but I had to sacrifice the laziness of the primary stream. As I posted in the comment above the problem which I tried to simplify mocking the code is about to read an excel file sheet by sheet (filtered by sheet's name) and traversing all rows to create objects accordingly to the data in the spreadsheet.

The original idea is still good to me but, apparently, `Stream.iterator()` implementation consumes each nested stream at the first `hasNext()` invocation operated at the creation of the first `A` object.

So I abandoned `flatMap()` and used `reduce(Stream::concat)` to concatenate all streams generated by `A.getBStream()`:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();
        Iterator<C> it = Stream.generate(() -> null)
                .takeWhile(y -> x.incrementAndGet() < 5)
                .filter(y -> x.get() % 2 == 0)
                .map(a -> new A("A" + x.get()))
                .map(A::getBStream)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .reduce(Stream::concat)
                .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(B::toC)
                .iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("after hasNext()");
            C next = it.next();
            System.out.println(next);
        }
    }
```

This produces the following output:

```
 > created A2
 > created A4
 >> created A2->B0
 >>> created A2->B0+C
after hasNext()
A2->B0+C
 >> created A2->B1
 >>> created A2->B1+C
after hasNext()
A2->B1+C
 >> created A2->B2
 >>> created A2->B2+C
after hasNext()
A2->B2+C
 >> created A2->B3
 >>> created A2->B3+C
after hasNext()
A2->B3+C
 >> created A2->B4
 >> created A4->B0
 >>> created A4->B0+C
after hasNext()
A4->B0+C
 >> created A4->B1
 >>> created A4->B1+C
after hasNext()
A4->B1+C
 >> created A4->B2
 >>> created A4->B2+C
after hasNext()
A4->B2+C
 >> created A4->B3
 >>> created A4->B3+C
after hasNext()
A4->B3+C
 >> created A4->B4
```

The price to pay is to have `A2` and `A4` generated up-front, but all the `B` objects are generated lazily

Comment: @YassinHajaj thanks, not perfect though! ;) :D

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest that I can think of which behaves that way you are wanting .  I'm putting it here to help with the discussion.  In your example, you have two identifiers; for one used when creating A objects, and the other used when creating B objects.  With this code, those identifiers are created up-front using the same logic that you had (although I replaced `AtomicInteger` with `IntStream`).  `flatmap` is still used, but not at object creation time.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class FreeRunner3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Iterator<C> iterator = IntStream.range(1, 5)
            .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(1, 5)
                    .filter(j -> j % 2 != 0)
                    .mapToObj(j -> new int[] { i, j }))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .map(id -> new A("A" + id[0]).toB(id[1]))
            .map(B::toC)
            .iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("after hasNext()");
            C next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(next);
        }

    }

    private static class A {
        private final String name;

        public A(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println(" > created " + name);
        }

        public B toB(int i) {
            return new B(this.name + "->B" + i);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static class B {
        private final String name;

        public B(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println(" >> created " + name);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public C toC() {
            return new C(this.name + "+C");
        }

    }

    private static class C {
        private final String name;

        public C(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println(" >>> created " + name);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

One difference with this implementation is that an instance of A is created for each instance of B.

```
 > created A2
 >> created A2->B1
 >>> created A2->B1+C
after hasNext()
A2->B1+C
 > created A2
 >> created A2->B3
 >>> created A2->B3+C
after hasNext()
A2->B3+C
 > created A4
 >> created A4->B1
 >>> created A4->B1+C
after hasNext()
A4->B1+C
 > created A4
 >> created A4->B3
 >>> created A4->B3+C
after hasNext()
A4->B3+C
```

---

I thought I would include this as well to help with the discussion (*hoping no down votes from anyone*).  It does the opposite of what you are wanting, eagerly creating all objects up-front before the iterator is called on.

```
Iterator<C> iterator = IntStream.range(1, 5)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> new A("A" + i))
        .flatMap(A::getBStream)
        .map(B::toC)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("after hasNext()");
    C next = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(next);
}
```

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks but can you include your answer into a single one? It will be easier.
Also, that's unfortunately not what OP is looking for

Comment: @Holger thanks for the feedback - I have incorporated your suggestions in to my example code.

Comment: @YassinHajaj thanks for the advice.  I have combined the two answers.  I know that my answer doesn't match what the OP is wanting, but I thought it might help spark further discussion which might lead to a better answer.

Comment: No problem for me @RonMcleod, maybe OP will find it useful indeed

Comment: Hi @RonMcLeod no, downvotes for me, I love discussions, but unfortunately as you were already saying it's not what I was looking for. The ultimate goal was to create fully lazy stream. The reason can't be inferred by the mock of course (I tried to simplify things but, actually, I created more confusion) but I have a big excel file and I don't want to overload the memory. 
The problem of your code, in perspective of my original request, is that it creates objects and it also consumes the first stream, which is unacceptable in my context. 
But thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an iterator and then do something *for each* element in it, you could simply use a `forEach` and do it directly in the Stream:

```java
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();
Stream.generate(() -> null)
        .takeWhile(y -> x.incrementAndGet() < 5)
        .filter(y -> x.get() % 2 == 0)
        .map(n -> new A("A" + x.get()))
        .flatMap(A::getBStream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(B::toC)
        .forEach(c -> {
            System.out.println("after (no) hasNext()");
            System.out.println(c);
        });
```

Output:

```java
 > created A2
 >> created A2->B1
 >>> created A2->B1+C
after (no) hasNext()
A2->B1+C
 >> created A2->B3
 >>> created A2->B3+C
after (no) hasNext()
A2->B3+C
 > created A4
 >> created A4->B1
 >>> created A4->B1+C
after (no) hasNext()
A4->B1+C
 >> created A4->B3
 >>> created A4->B3+C
after (no) hasNext()
A4->B3+C
```

If you need to return the list, instead, you could simply return a Stream:

```java
AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger();
Stream<C> stream = Stream.generate(() -> null)
        .takeWhile(y -> x.incrementAndGet() < 5)
        .filter(y -> x.get() % 2 == 0)
        .map(n -> new A("A" + x.get()))
        .flatMap(A::getBStream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(B::toC);

// return it here

stream.forEach(c -> {
    System.out.println("after (no) hasNext()");
    System.out.println(c);
});
```

The output would be the same.

Comment: `forEach()` indeed works and it doesn't consume the nested stream upfront, but this way, solving the problem in a "pure" functional way, doesn't allow me to return an Iterable over the lazy-generated list of `C` objects. In other words I can't use the code to return any kind of iterable or enumerable object.